# How to delete selected rows from UltraGrid and database after validation of each row?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, infragistics

The following function is implemented to to remove all selected rows if met the condition from UltraGrid and from database:

```
    private void RemoveRows()
    {
        foreach (var row in dgvReceords.Selected.Rows)
        {
            var order = row.Cells["Order"].Value;
            if (order== null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                // Update database via business object and then update grid
                OrderBO.DeleteByPrimaryKey(row.Cells["Id"].Text);
                if (OrderBO.Save() == SaveResult.Success)
                    row.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem it fails to iterate through all rows and always leave one row behind. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `foreach()` uses collection that the `.Delete()` are modifying. Try to use `for()` and remove in reverse order:

```
private void RemoveRows()
{
    for (var i=dgvReceords.Selected.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var row = dgvReceords.Selected.Rows[i];
        var order = row.Cells["Order"].Value;
        if (order== null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.ToString().Trim()))
        {
            // Update database via business object and then update grid
            OrderBO.DeleteByPrimaryKey(row.Cells["Id"].Text);
            if (OrderBO.Save() == SaveResult.Success)
                dgvReceords.Selected.Rows[i].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```